# Mysql workbench is not compatible with Mariadb ... and it doesn't work

Tags: macos, mariadb, mysql-workbench

Mysql workbench returns this error:

```
Incompatible/nonstandard server version or connection protocol detected (11.3.2).

A connection to this database can be established but some MySQL Workbench features may not work properly since the database is not fully compatible with the supported versions of MySQL.
```

I got the warning earlier, but the instrument still worked. Now, after an operating system upgrade on MAC, it no longer works and returns:

```
Tables could not be fetched
Views could not be fetched ...
```

The MAC OS now is Sonoma 14.3.1.

mariadb version is: from 11.3.2-MariaDB, client 15.2 for osx10.19 (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper

Mysql workbench is 8.0.36

A work around and installation of an alternative tool is also fine.

Comment: just use the mariadb command line client?  workbench doesn't always even keep up with new mysql versions, not surprising it doesn't work with a newer mariadb version.  surprising that an os upgrade made a difference, though; are you certain nothing else was updated at that time?